# Where can I find European Patent Office documents?

Tags: european

We are trying to get a European patent issued through our patent attorney in Munich. To save money, we would like to send him a first draft of a response to the examiner's rejection for lack of inventive step.

But I cannot find any examples of what form that response would take. Is there anyway to find those kinds of documents online?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find what I was looking for at the [European Patent Register](https://register.epo.org/). I found a patent application that looked promising and then clicked on "All documents" on a menu on the side. That gave me a list of all correspondence between the European Patent Office and the applicant. Some of those were exactly the examples I was looking for.